# Wordpress create table by plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How create table (if not exists) by activation plugin?
Note: plugin works fine if table exists, but i need create table if not exists
what i try:

```
function alicelf_bookmark() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "alice_user_bookmarks";
    $charset_collate = '';

    if ( ! empty( $wpdb->charset ) )
        $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$wpdb->charset}";

    if ( ! empty( $wpdb->collate ) )
        $charset_collate .= " COLLATE {$wpdb->collate}";

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        user_id INT,
        name VARCHAR(255),
        shipping_address VARCHAR(255),
        user_notes TEXT,
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    //some other plugin stuff..
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'alicelf_bookmark');
```

Maybe im use wrong action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your plugin requires it's own table, you will want to take into account that this table can change over time. You know it will change (from nothing to your first version) on first install. Later it can change when a user updates the plugin.

A great way to do this is to store a database version number in the options table, and check if it's updated. If the version number in the options table doesn't match the one in your plugin, an install is needed.

This brings us to how your plugin should handle changes in the table structure. A simple approach could include a whole lot of if-tests and custom ALTER TABLE queries (the same queries aren't necesserily needed when upgrading from 1.0 to 3.0 as the ones you would need to upgrade from 1.0 to 3.0). This could become hard to work with pretty fast.

It is generally better to leave the ALTER TABLE statements to WordPress' own dbDelta function, which will generate the statements you need.

```
<?php
$prefix_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'prefix_table_name';
$prefix_db_version = '1.0';
$prefix_db_installed_version = get_option( 'prefix_db_version' );

/**
 * Create or update tables if needed.
 */
function prefix_install_db() {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( $prefix_db_installed_version == $prefix_db_version )
        return; // Database is current version, no need to do anything

    // We'll need dbDelta()
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $prefix_table_name . " (
        ID bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        email varchar(320) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  ID(ID)
    );";
    dbDelta( $sql );

    update_option( 'prefix_db_version' , $prefix_db_version );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'prefix_install_db' );
```

For further reading, a great guide to [Creating Tables with Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) can be found in the Codex.

Comment: Hmm i dnt think about plugin versions.
Thank u i will update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: Just need register activate and change wp_head instead wp_footer

```
add_action('wp_head', 'alicelf_bookmark');

//also move away your activation and sql create table  to another func for escape some errors 
//when you enable plugin and table exists
function activator_bookmark(){
//do code
}

register_activation_hook(FILE,'activator_bookmark');
```